# How to solve generic pronunciation problems for Watson text to speech?

Tags: ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I use Jupiter notepad for Watson TTS.
French pronunciation have a generic problem.
I'm close to a neophyte, with just some JS/php/lua development basics. I struggled to install everything properly.

Watson French Mâle voice bypasses "ze" pronunciation if the word ending with "ze" precedes a word starting with a consonant.
Exemple
exemple : Il personnalise pour watson. Il personnalise avec watson.

I think i'm on IBM Cloud.
French langage.
Nicolas Voice.

i try understand docs as cloud.ibm.com/docs/, but it is no simple to understand. Installation on jupiter asked me 3 differents youtube tutorials to have watson workings.

Now I have to understand the method to follow to correct the pre-existing voices.
I don't need to create a new one.

Have a nice day

Comment: What is your setup (IBM Cloud / Cloud Pak)? What input language, voice? What is an example for wrong pronounciation? What documentation have you looked at? Add that to the question.

Comment: Hello.

I think i'm on IBM Cloud. French langage. Nicolas Voice. 
It as same problem on demo web page.

exemple : Il personnalise pour watson. Il personnalise avec watson. 
"ze" of firt purpose is not say : Il personnali(se) pour watson.
I looked https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/ 
I understand it is possible to change <phoneme> of a word. But here the problem is generic for all words ended by "ze".

Comment: The French documentation for Text to Speech is available here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/text-to-speech?topic=text-to-speech-gettingStarted&locale=fr In order for someone to help you here on Stack Overflow, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please add more details. The exact problem is not clear.

Comment: Sorry for that.
I'm already on the French doc.
I went through as many pages as possible on all the documentation and the api.
But i'm not dev.

It seems that I am not clear and precise enough.
So I will detail.

If a word ends with the sound "ze", the pronunciation of the sound "ze" does not occur when the word that follows begins with a consonant.
This for all words. It is a global problem.

For example: "I customize with Watson. I customize for watson."

We hear: "I personalize with Watson. I personalize for Watson."

Have a nice day

Comment: Impossible to modify :(
Translation problem.
I mean : 
Write : Je personnalise avec watson. Je personnalise pour watson.
ear : Je personnalise avec watson. Je personnali pour watson